# chart.js - horizontalBar stacked chart with xaxis as dates

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am looking to create a bar chart but have had a hell of a time trying to find what I need through chart.js 2.1

Goal is to have a chart that looks like this:
[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqDXv.png)

So far I have been unsuccessful getting the xAxis to reflect dates.

Here's the story:
yAxis are vendor groups that have stacking due dates (the dates may/may not match up with another vendor group). Each stack has a numeric value as well, but this does not affect the layout of the chart, just an overlay of data.
xAxis are all the due dates, starting with the current date and moving on.

Any assistance or jfiddle examples would be EXTREMELY helpful!

Here's what I have today: https://jsfiddle.net/npk3xdb0/

HTML:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="bar-chart-horizontal" width="200" height="50"></canvas>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart-horizontal"), {
  type: "horizontalBar",
  data: {
    labels: ['V1','V2','V3'],
    datasets: [{ data: [50, 60, 75], backgroundColor: "#8C453E"},{ data: [50, 70, 85], backgroundColor: "#684796"},{ data: [50, 53, 111], backgroundColor: "#427780"},{ data: [19, , ], backgroundColor: "#599647"}]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: { enabled: false },
    hover :{ animationDuration:0 },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: { beginAtZero:true, fontFamily: "'Open Sans Bold', sans-serif", fontSize:11 },
        scaleLabel:{ display:false },
        gridLines: { }, 
        stacked: true
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: { display:false, color: "#fff", zeroLineColor: "#fff", zeroLineWidth: 0 },
        ticks: { fontFamily: "'Open Sans Bold', sans-serif", fontSize:11 },
        stacked: true
      }]
    },
    legend:{ display:false },
    animation: {
      onComplete: function () {
        var chartInstance = this.chart;
        var ctx = chartInstance.ctx;
        ctx.textAlign = "right";
        ctx.font = "9px Open Sans";
        ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";

        Chart.helpers.each(this.data.datasets.forEach(function (dataset, i) {
          var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
          Chart.helpers.each(meta.data.forEach(function (bar, index) {
            data = dataset.data[index];
            //if(i==0){
            //    ctx.fillText(data, 20, bar._model.y+4);
            //} else {
            ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x-3, bar._model.y+4);
            //}
          }),this)
        }),this);
      }
    },
    pointLabelFontFamily : "Quadon Extra Bold",
    scaleFontFamily : "Quadon Extra Bold",
  }
});
```

Comment: I feel like you need another type of chart.. If you need dates to be displayed, I'd better use a [gantt chart](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/samples/), because the chart you are using is supposed to show the quantity of the bars, not dates..